# Bash loop through date time +%Y-%m-%d %H:%M format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Purpose of this code is to print 1 minute interval from an hour ago. I have below code, but having trouble looping between the from and to date

```
to_dt=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`
from_dt=`date -d "${to_dt} 1 hour ago"  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`

echo $from_dt $to_dt

2017-08-04 01:54 2017-08-04 02:54

while [ "${from_dt}" -lt "${to_dt}" ] 
do
    
    from_dt=`date -d "${from_dt} 1 minute" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`
    end_dt_min_after=`date -d "${from_dt} 1 minute" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`
    
done
```

I get below error

> **line 10: [: 2017-08-04 02:01: integer expression expected**

Expected result:

> **2017-08-04 01:55 2017-08-04 02:56**
>
> **2017-08-04 01:56 2017-08-04 02:57**
>
> ....
>
> ....

is it possible to iterate using while i.e. increment from date by 1 minute during each loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used epoc for simplicity here. Should work for your use case:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z $1 ];then
echo Please pass number of seconds
exit 1
fi

epoc_now=`date "+%s"`

epoc_after_hour=`expr $epoc_now + $1`

while [ "${epoc_after_hour}" -gt "${epoc_now}" ]
do
        epoc_now=`expr $epoc_now + 60`
        date -d "@$epoc_now"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I played around this use cause and was able to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

I would handle numeric timestamps until the time of printing.
So you start with:

```
from_dt=$(($(date +%s -d "1 hour ago")))
to_dt=$(($(date +%s)))
```

In the loop increment from_dt by 60 each time and then print the timestamp in readable format:

```
echo "$(date -d @$from_dt)"
```

Comment: Thanks, similar use case as @asatsi. But, I liked to use "1 Hour ago" than subtract seconds as this give the flexibility to go to a month back, very easily.

Answer (score 0):

`-lt` operator expects both operands to be integer.

You should convert your date variables to EPOCH seconds value before running a loop.

```
to_dt=$(date "+%s")
from_dt=$(date -d "@$to_dt" -d "-1 hour"  "+%s")

while [ "$from_dt" -lt "$to_dt" ]; do
   # add 1 minute
   from_dt=$(date -d "@$from_dt" -d "+1 minute" '+%s')
   echo "inside the loop"
done
```

Comment: Loops only once for some reason, I see from_dt inside while is greater than to_date. Although, we have set from_dt less than to_dt